# What properties single out $ \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{k}) $-schemes that are quasi-projective varieties over $ \mathbb{k} $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space, zariski-topology, ringed-spaces

I have a question in algebraic geometry that I would like to ask:

> Let $ \mathbb{k} $ be an algebraically closed field. Is there a property $ P $, phrased in the language of schemes, such that every $ \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{k}) $-scheme $ (X,\mathcal{O}) $ is isomorphic to the $ \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{k}) $-scheme associated with a quasi-projective variety over $ \mathbb{k} $ **if and only if** $ X $ satisfies $ P $?

By *isomorphism*, I mean one between locally ringed spaces.

By *quasi-projective variety*, I mean a Zariski-open subset of a projective variety (i.e. an irreducible projective algebraic set) in $ {\mathbf{P}^{n}}(\mathbb{k}) $ (the projective $ n $-space over $ \mathbb{k} $) for some $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.

I am guessing that $ P $ would have to include properties like ‘integral’, ‘separated’ and ‘of finite-type’, but I am not sure if these are sufficient.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the analogous question in the complex setting see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_embedding_theorem. The answer presumably involves the existence of some line bundle on $P$ having some nice properties.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks for bringing this to my attention! I’ve heard of the Kodaira Embedding Theorem but never bothered to check it out.

Comment: Following up on Qiaochu's comment, I think the only plausible answer is that $X$ carries an ample line bundle (=invertible sheaf). That's more or less a tautology, but for example schemes proper over a field, there are non-tautologous characterisations of ampleness such as Serre's criterion.